# How can I see Facebook notifications older than one week?

Tags: facebook

The page https://www.facebook.com/notifications only lists the notifications I have received over the last seven days. How can I see Facebook notifications older than that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.  The linked page is not restricted to 7 days as it may have been in 2013

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken you can view all notifications by going to the Activity Log.

1. Click on your name
2. Click Activity Log next to Update Info
3. From there you can view different types of notifications by sorting the different notifications or by date.

---

**Resource**

[View All Facebook Notifications On One Page](http://www.twelveskip.com/tutorials/facebook/478/view-all-facebook-notifications-in-one-page)

Comment: The items in Activity Log are not the same as Notifications.

Activity Log shows you things *you* did.
Notifications show you things other people did, related to you or things you did (like, comment, tag).

Comment: @Rikki It appears to me that the activity log *does* show other people's activity. Note that there is a checkbox in the upper-right that, if checked, will only show *your* activity; unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to show everything *except* your activity. Still, it's better than nothing, which is good, because I took about a year-long break from Facebook and was afraid I wouldn't be able to find any of the notifications I missed.

Comment: Though actually, I'm not sure it shows comments posted in response to you in threads on other people's posts, if you're not tagged in said comments...other than that, I can't think of anything it doesn't appear to show.

Comment: @KyleStrand: we must be getting different version of Facebook. I have ticked and unticked the checkbox (it adds and removes &filter_onlyme=on from the URL), I have "All" selected on the left hand side and every single entry in the Activity Log is "Rikki Prince commented...", "Rikki Prince likes...", "Rikki Prince wrote..." and "Rikki Prince sent...". Very bizarre!

Comment: @Rikki So you don't even see entries for when people have written on your wall or tagged you in a photo? (I guess I wouldn't be *too* surprised if this is a difference between facebook versions, since they tend to roll out changes to different users at different times...)

Comment: @KyleStrand Yeah, I've double checked again and I'm only getting activity by me. Must be a roll out issue. I also still don't have graph search!

Comment: I can confirm, Activity Log does *not* show all notifications. For example if someone invited my to an event (that I ignored) a month ago, this will not show up in activity log.

This is the case irrespective of whether "Include  Only Me activity" is ticked or not.